# Vue: Error in when populate template tag of single file component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-sfc

I getting an error when I put something inside the  in my single file component

[image]

Here is my Home.vue file:

```
<template>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Here is my main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

window.Vue = Vue
Vue.use(VueRouter)

window.axios = axios

import router from './routes';


new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    mounted: function() {
        console.log('lol')
    }
})
```

Here is my routes.js file:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

let routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: require('./views/Home.vue')
    }
]

export default new VueRouter({
    routes
});
```

When the template tag is empty the error goes away.

Comment: component is expecting a function, so instead of `component: require('./views/Home.vue')` do `component: () => import('./views/Home.vue')`

Comment: this did not work, same error :(

Comment: I downgraded the vue-loader from 16.x to 15.9 and it worked